# Get tangent of spline points in kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

how is it possible to get the tangent of Spline points of Kinetic.Spline. I'm using KineticJS  4.7.2.

Havn't found any method so far providing this for me.

Many thanks, Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kinetic spline is a combination of quadratic/Bezier curves (unless tension==0)

Therefore you can *approximate* the tangent at each spline point in at least 2 ways.

**The rough approximation is a 4-step process:**

1. Use mySpline.getPoints() to get all the connection points in your spline.
2. Use Math.atan2 to calculate the radian angles of the incoming/outgoing lines at connection points.
3. Take the difference of those 2 angles (giving the radian angle at that connection point).
4. Take the tangent of that radian angle.

**The better approximation is more involved:**

1. Use the internal spline.allPoints to get the control points of all the curves making up the spline.  Hint: The first & last curves are quadratic, all the others are cubic Bezier.
2. At each point connecting 2 curves, find a point very near the end of the incoming curve.
3. At each point connecting 2 curves, find a point very near the beginning of the outgoing curve.
4. Use Math.atan2 to calculate the angle of a line segment connecting those 2 points.
5. Take the tangent of that radian angle.

**Getting XY points along a curve**

These functions will help you get the XY along a quadratic or cubic bezier curve.

If T=0.00, the point will be at the very beginning of the curve.

If T==1.00, the point will be at the very end of the curve.

```
// quadratic bezier: T is 0-1
function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt,endPt,T) {
    var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
    var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
    return( {x:x,y:y} );
}

// cubic bezier T is 0-1
function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(pct, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = pct * pct;
    var t3 = t2 * pct;
    return a + (-a * 3 + pct * (3 * a - a * pct)) * pct
    + (3 * b + pct * (-6 * b + b * 3 * pct)) * pct
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * pct) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

And if you need to refer to the KineticJS source code for a spline, here it is:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/a2a4c6df2b231e9c133e67a80f49a9ac420e2f33/src/shapes/Spline.js

Comment: This really is a well researched answer.